# Spring Boot add Request Body in the Error Response Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have my own Exceptionhandler which is extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

I am able to capture the error but the request body is empty at the time of error response creation

```
override fun handleHttpMessageNotReadable(e:HttpMessageNotReadableException, headers:HttpHeaders , status:HttpStatus , webRequest: WebRequest):ResponseEntity<Any>{
        val rsp = ErrResponse(
                Data(
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name,
                        e.message!!
                ),**REQUEST-BODY-NEEDED**[customFilter.payload])
        return super.handleExceptionInternal(e, rsp,headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, webRequest)
    }
```

So i have used customRequestfilter to get the body and captured the body there but the order precendence is low for customRequestFilter it will be get executed only after the request . So is there a any way to Capture the request body on the error response?

CustomRequestFilter

```
@Component
public class CustomRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

 public String payload;
    public Map<String, Object> reqLog =null;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

        int status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value();

        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
        if (status == response.getStatus()) {
            reqLog = getTrace(wrappedRequest, status);
            payload = getBody(wrappedRequest, reqLog);/** ITS CAPTURING THE BODY HERE SUCCESSFULLY**/
            logTrace(wrappedRequest, reqLog); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is Kotlin, not Java. I'll edit the tags.

Comment: Where are you throwing the HttpMessageNotReadable exception? Is it thrown internally the Spring Framework? Just checked, it is thrown from HttpMessageConverter

Comment: Yep its thrown by spring

Comment: LppEdd Seconds part of code written in Java. Just a mixed between java and kotlin because the second part gonna be library for other projects as well which are java based

Comment: @LppEdd thanks for this. not only the solution but the way you came to this. in hindsight it looks trivial to look at the spring code and wrap things in your own classes but somehow I overlooked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that was tricky! Anyway...

Create your custom `HttpInputMessage`, which will delegate to the original one.

```
class CachedHttpInputMessage implements HttpInputMessage {
    private final HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;

    CachedHttpInputMessage(final HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage) {
        this.httpInputMessage = httpInputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            final InputStream body = httpInputMessage.getBody();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while (true) {
                final int length;
                if (!((length = body.read(buffer)) > -1)) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return httpInputMessage.getHeaders();
    }
}
```

Build your custom `HttpMessageConverter`, extending the right one based on the currently used one (`Jackson`, `Gson`, etc.), and register it as first.

```
class CustomHttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    @Override
    public Object read(
            final Type type,
            final Class<?> contextClass,
            final HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        return super.read(type, contextClass, new CachedHttpInputMessage(inputMessage));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(
            final Class<?> clazz,
            final HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        return super.readInternal(clazz, new CachedHttpInputMessage(inputMessage));
    }
}
```

(alternatively you could create a generic wrapper, like with the `CachedHttpInputMessage`, and wrap each pre-configured `HttpMessageConverter`, just update the list passed as input to `extendMessageConverters`)

---

```
@Configuration
class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(0, new CustomHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    ...
 }
```

---

Throw away the custom `Filter`, and inside the `ExceptionHandler` read the body using

```
final HttpInputMessage inputMessage = e.getHttpInputMessage();
final InputStream body = inputMessage.getBody();
```

Done!
Remember to clean-up the code a bit and handle all the possible exceptions.

Comment: I am getting Stream closed error when i try to read the body 
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(PushbackInputStream.java:74)
 at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:135)

Comment: @sankar are you maintaining the ContentCachingRequestWrapper?

Comment: I have commented those while executing the e.getHttpInputMessage().

Comment: @sankar I think you need to still use it inside the Filter, and pass that to the filter chain. Otherwise the InputStream will be closed.

Comment: Ok now also i am getting the same error. Now i am passing wrappedRequest to the filterchain its kind of weird this should be handled inside the framework 
filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);

Comment: @sankar wait. I'll build a small example on my own and let you know.

Comment: Thanks buddy how did you got that idea :). Its better solution than requestWrapper and CustomFilter

Comment: @sankar a lot of debugging hahaha

Comment: if we need to get msg body commonly for all type of exception can we able to read it from Request ?

Comment: @sankar in case you have problems it is better to post another question with more details on that specific problem.

Comment: found the solution just extended same httpinputmessage thanks